# Generating random labelled trees

Tags: graph-theory, randomized-algorithms, tree

I am looking for a simple rejection-free algorithm to uniformly sample random labelled trees (i.e. to generate each of them with the same probability).

One possibility is to generate Prüfer sequences and convert them to trees, but this is not very simple when thought of as a construction procedure.  I was wondering is there was a simpler, more direct construction that still guarantees uniform sampling?

Comment: Alonso's bijective algorithm is worth looking into. It's efficient and rejection free. It's described in Chapter 4 of [*Random Generation of Trees: Random Generators in Computer Science*](https://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780792395287) (1994)